# How can I use an external python library in AWS Glue?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, openpyxl, aws-glue

First stack overflow question here. Hope I do this correctly:

I need to use an external python library in AWS glue. "Openpyxl" is the name of the library.

I follow these directions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html

However, after I have my zip file saved in the correct s3 location and point my glue job to that location, I'm not sure what to actually write in the script.

I tried your typical `Import openpyxl` , but that just returns the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named openpyxl
```

Obviously I don't know what to do here - also relatively new to programming so I'm not sure if this is a noob question or what. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it spark job or python shell job?

Answer (score 16):

It depends if the job is Spark or Python Shell.
For Spark you just need to zip the library and then when you point the job to the library S3 path, the job will import it. You just need to make sure that the zip contains this file: `__init__.py`

For example, for the library you are trying to import, if you download it from https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/#files, you can zip the folder **openpyxl** inside the **openpyxl-3.0.0.tar.gz**, and store it in S3.

---

On the other hand, if it is a Python Shell job, a zip file will not work. You will need to create an **egg** file from the library.
If you are using this version openpyxl-3.0.0, then you can download it from that same website, extract everything, and run the command `python setup.py bdist_egg` or **python3** instead of **python** if you use python3 instead.

This will generate an **egg** file inside `dist` folder which is also generated. You just need to put that egg file in S3 and point the Glue Job Python Libraries to that path.

If you already have the library and for some reason you don't have the `setup.py`, then you must create it in order to run the command to generate the egg file. Please refer to http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/12/python-101-easy_install-or-how-to-create-eggs/. There you can find an example.

Comment: For python shell, there is no need to download and bundle in egg file.

You can use `install_requires=['openpyxl==3.0.0']` in `setup.py` and it will download and install in glue during execution.

Comment: As Sandeep said, this build process is only needed for custom user libraries. Right now wheels work fine, so no eggs needed. I am still trying to understand their rationale for requiring different formats with Spark vs. Shell though. Would it make things too easy?

Comment: This might be a silly question but can you also add .json files to the external library zip and access it through the glue script?

Answer (score 8):

You can now (as of Glue version 2) directly add external libraries using `--additional-python-modules` parameter.

For example to update or to add a new scikit-learn module use the following key/value:

`"--additional-python-modules", "scikit-learn==0.21.3"`.

More details could be found in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/reduced-start-times-spark-etl-jobs.html).

Comment: It is not working for it, it still gives no module error. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I spent several hours in the last few days and I could not find a way to make it work.

#### 1. Using a Spark Notebook

In a notebook one can specify something like this in the first cell:

`%additional_python_modules ["pydantic==1.10.12"]`

But it doesn't work. The notebook shows promising logs such as this one:

```
Applying the following default arguments:
--glue_kernel_version 0.38.1
--enable-glue-datacatalog true
--additional_python_modules ["pydantic==1.10.12"]
```

But it actually doesn't import the library (you get a `ModuleNotFoundError` when trying to import it).

Other configurations in a notebook, such as writing the following code in a cell:

```
%extra_py_files s3://some-bucket/scripts/some_library.zip
```

Also do not work despite showing promising logs, such as this one:

```
Extra py files to be included:
s3://some-bucket/scripts/pymongo/pymongo.zip
```

#### 2. Using spark scripts.

I also tried creating a spark script. I uploaded a zip file with the package containing an `__init__.py` file and configured the path in the job details (as shown in the image below), but it didn't work.

[image: Configuring job s3 path]

Again I saw AWS Logs that seemed to indicate that everything was working well:

```
23/10/11 20:04:02 INFO SparkContext: 
Added file pymongo.zip at spark://172.35.246.64:43003/files/pymongo.zip with timestamp 1697054641877
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use following boilerplate code to use extra files as well as external libraries - https://github.com/fatangare/aws-python-shell-deploy