# Unable to import psycopg2 in AWS Glue

Tags: python, psycopg2, aws-glue

I am trying to import psycopg2 in my Python based AWS Glue Script.

I have uploaded it's egg file in s3 (which I got it using pip install psycopg2-binary AND base files from pypi itself) but issue remains same,

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'
```

Please guide in right direction, Thanks

Links I tried : [How can I use an external python library in AWS Glue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58205999/how-can-i-use-an-external-python-library-in-aws-glue)

PS : If you need some more resources, do tell me in comments

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the Glue job parameter:

```
--additional_python_modules psycopg2-binary
```

Once you  have that you can import normally using `import psycopg2`